# Can I set a MongoDB value to a javascript expression?

Tags: mongodb

From the documentation I read you can do this:

```
 db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $set: { n : 1 } } );
```

( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating )

Now I would like to set it to a dynamic value like a counter or expression:

```
var i = 0;
db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $set: { n : $i++ } } );

db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $set: { n : ${new Date()} } } );
```

Is this possible ?

I would also accept any solution that does not need to modify and save the full document.

Comment: Do you know what `$inc` does? the examples you gave doesn't make much/any sense

Comment: Sorry I ment set. I correct my mistake, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongo is an extended javascript shell with mongodb support, so you can do anything that you can do with plain javascript:

```
var i = 0;
db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $set: { n : i++ } } );
```

and

```
db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $set: { n : new Date() } } );
```

**Update**

ah so.. that's not going to work. You have to update each document invidually! JS is executed before you pass that query to the database. Effectly you're doing the following:

```
db.foo.update( {}, { $set: { n : 0 } }, false, true ); # i was zero here
i++;
```

As I said, you have to update each document individually, but you can execute the whole thing on server-side with `db.eval( )` to speed up things a little bit;)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it seems that i++ is only evaluated once thus all documents get the same value (1). I guess it makes sense. But I am still looking for a way to assign an expression that is evaluated each time.

Comment: no it's evaluated each time. you're doing something wrong, show the code. maybe you're storing the result (object) and hoping it will evaluate again?

Comment: I tried it again, see new answer ( I couldn't get it to properly format as a comment... )

Comment: yes, I did this in the end: `db.eval(function() {db.people.find().forEach( function(obj) {obj.n = new Date();db.people.save(obj);} );});` Thanks for all your help !